# RegEx for Google Form requiring Specific Number Format

Tags: regex, google-forms

I need to limit an accepted text response to be only in the following format:

1234567.123 AorABorABCD (1or12)

So, 7-digits.3-digits 1-4Letters (1-3-digits)

This is a SKU number, followed by 1-4 letters noting size (S or YM or SMMD) followed by 1-3 digits noting quantity needed.

Any help is appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\d{7}\.\d{3}\s[A-Za-z]{1,4}
```

Explanation:
**\d{7}** - matches 7 digits
**\.** matches the dot (".")
**\d{3}** - again, matches 3 digits
**\s** - matches a whitespace
**[A-Za-z]{1,4}** - matches 1-4 letters from A to Z no matter the case.

Will match:

`1234567.123 AABd
1534567.113 AaAA
4586451.773 dasA
1231846.123 A
1234567.123 Ao
1234567.123 Aor
1234567.123 AorA
1234567.123 AorA
1234567.123 AorA`

Also, if you do not need all letters from A to Z change the range accordingly.

EDIT: Forgot the slash before the dot, mind the changed content.

You can try it [here](http://www.regexr.com/3bhcf)

Comment: Many thanks, Asunez! This is my first attempt at regex and you breaking it down for me really helped. I was even able to tweak it a bit as needed.

Comment: @K.Bahr No problem. If you need more explanation on more regexes you can visit [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) page where you can split regex for more information.

Comment: @ Asunez Struggling with one issue --- I'm utilizing this in Google Forms and the final RegEx I ended-up with tests perfectly, and is accepted in GF,  as a single entry response, BUT, if the response is a list of multiple entries that match, it will not accept them. Only a single response. Is there a trick to accepting multiple matches?

Comment: @K.Bahr - I've never used Google Forms before, can't help you with that. My guess is that is GF specific. Maybe a multiline parameter to this regex?